# How to differentiate a directive's templateUrl value in dev and production mode?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

As we all know, a directive can have a `template` and a `templateUrl` members. For large html template the `templateUrl` should be used.

I need to use the latter but I don't know how I can have different file structure for dev and production without rewriting `templateUrl`'s value.

For example,

- in my dev I need to write `templateUrl: 'src/angular/components/[feature]/[feature].html'`
- in my production I need to have `templateUrl: 'views/components/...'`

Is there a way I can approach this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `$http` interceptor and replace special tokens in you URL based on a different config.

Example:

```
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
         $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q) {
             return {
                 'request': function (config) {
                     config.url = modifyYourURL(config.url); // MODIFY THE URL
                     return config || $q.when(config);
                 }
             }
         });
     });
```